# If all eigenvalues are 1 or -1, is then $A^{12}=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

True or false: If all the eigenvalues of A are either $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda = -1$ then $A^{12}$= I

If we have a matrix $$\mathbf A = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$ this has eigenvalues of 1 or -1 then $$\mathbf A = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda-1&0\\0&\lambda+1\end{pmatrix}$$ and if we plug in $\lambda=1 $ $$\mathbf A = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$$ So $A^{12}$ $\neq$ I

Is this a correct way of proving this is false?

Comment: No, in your example $A^{12}=I$.

Comment: You cannot make A equal to two different things

Comment: Why can you substitute $\lambda=1$? Are you suggesting that $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$?!

Comment: No, the point is that this "equality" is obviously absurd and therefore the statement is false. The logic is wrong but not because the "equality" is false.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 6):

Compute powers of the matrix $A$, where
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

You will find that 
$$A^n=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

**Remark:** If a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ has *both* $1$ and $-1$ as eigenvalues, then we will have $A^2=I$. But we can find a $3\times 3$ matrix that has both $1$ and $-1$ as eigenvalues such that $A^n\ne I$ for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: How come user142299's argument does not work?

Comment: @mathguy: Because Andre's matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @EricStucky Oh yea..right...lol

Comment: I thought the question was assuming that the matrix is diagonalizable... isn't it getting at the argument given in my post? What is the "lesson" of this problem?

Comment: @user142299: Possibly a concrete example of how diagonalizability makes matrices more well behaved?

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial is $p(\lambda) = \lambda^2-1$. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we have $A^2-I = 0$. Hence, $A^{12} = I$.

Comment: The OP did not say that the matrix is $2\times2$, so we do not know the degree of the polynomial. Even for the $2\times2$ matrices the counterexample $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ given in another answer works.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is not necessarily $\lambda^2-1$.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, $\mathbf A^2=\mathbf I$ (easy to check by hand) and therefore $\mathbf A^{12}=(\mathbf A^2)^6=\mathbf I^6=\mathbf I$. Andre Nicolas explains a correct reason that the answer is in fact "False".

Your method does not work because you were confusing two operations. In line 2 you replaced $\mathbf A$ with $\lambda \mathbf I - \mathbf A$ but this is what we do when trying to find the eigenvalues (we want the determinant of this matrix to be zero).

To compute large powers of a (diagonalizable) matrix, we instead diagonalize it $\mathbf A = \mathbf S \Lambda \mathbf S$ and then raise $\Lambda$ to the same power: $\mathbf A^n = \mathbf S \Lambda^n \mathbf S$.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Use the decomposition in terms of eigenvalues. (Sorry i called this the "SVD" the first time, haven't used lin alg acronyms in a while). Since the eigenvalues are roots of 1, we know that $D^{12}=I$ because 12 is even. So $$A^{12}=SD^{12}S^{-1}=SIS^{-1}=SS^{-1}=I$$ as desired.

However, you would have to check that the matrix is actually diagonalizable in all instances. I'm not sure if the question is assuming this or not.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. You are using the SVD, this means $A = UV^T$, where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices (since the singular values are $1$). If you want a decomposition as $SDS^{-1}$, then you are assuming that the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: @mathguy: But $\Sigma=I$; I'm sure that's what the parenthetical note was supposed to mean.